# Does the same CNN model needs different learning rates for different datasets?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, tf.keras, hyperparameters

I using convolutional neural network models for medical image segmentation. When I train the models (for example Tiramisu model[1](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017_workshops/w13/papers/Jegou_The_One_Hundred_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf)), I tried the same learning rates recommended in the paper, however, I am getting bad results.

My concern is, do we need to find a different optimal learning rate when we use the model for different dataset. For example, in this case, they use CamVid dataset (streets, cars, people and so on) and I am using medical images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there might be some set of parameters that work well enough for most cases(which usually end up being the defaults of several libraries), the optimal choice is very dataset dependant. Using the ones from a paper is a good starting point to have a baseline, but never let than stop you from trying out changing them.

Another important point is the loss function, a loss function that might work well for segmenting cars (they are big, over 20% of image), might not work well for something like text (small, less than 1% of image).

If you have a binary segmentation, playing around with threshold for deciding if the pixel is or not the class you want is also important.

Comment: Thanks a lot @juvian. If you know any paper that wich mentions that, it would be helpful.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, after reading several you start noticing many are using almost same architecture but have a change in their loss function / parameters, giving different results. You can try searching segmentation unbalanced.

Comment: This is mentioned in this paper if someone is interested.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09820